# How to uninstall the non-stop (continue on floating-point exceptions) mode?

Tags: c, exception, floating-point, language-lawyer

C11, 7.6.4.2 The `feholdexcept` function, Description, 2 (emphasis added):

> The feholdexcept function saves the current floating-point environment in the object
> pointed to by envp, clears the floating-point status flags, and then **installs a non-stop
> (continue on floating-point exceptions) mode, if available, for all floating-point
> exceptions**.<sup>218</sup>

Footnote 218:

> IEC 60559 systems have a default non-stop mode, and typically at least one other mode for trap
> handling or aborting; if the system provides only the non-stop mode then installing it is trivial. For
> such systems, the feholdexcept function can be used in conjunction with the feupdateenv
> function to write routines that hide spurious floating-point exceptions from their callers

A simple question: How to uninstall the non-stop (continue on floating-point exceptions) mode?

---

UPD20220725. Got an answer from Fred J. Tydeman (Vice-chair of PL22.11 (ANSI "C")):

> Standard C does not provide any way to do that.

Hence, it may be a defect. To be continued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Fred J. Tydeman (Vice-chair of PL22.11 (ANSI "C")):

> Standard C does not provide any way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

> How to uninstall the non-stop (continue on floating-point
> exceptions) mode?

You can call the [`feupdateenv` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feupdateenv), passing it the address of the environment object saved when you (last) called `feholdexcept`:

```c
#include <fenv.h>

double foo(double arg)
{
    fenv_t saved_mode;
    feholdexcept(&saved_mode);
    double result = arg;
    // do stuff ...

    feupdateenv(&saved_mode); // restore
    return result;
}
```

Alternatively, if you *don't* want to "remember the currently raised exceptions" and then (re-)raise them after the restoration, you can call the [`fsetenv` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feenv) to restore the saved environment, instead.

---

**Note:** On the issue raised (in the comments) on whether or not a call to either `feupdateenv` or `fsetenv` (with a pointer to an appropriate saved environment) will actually uninstall the "non-stop" (continue on FP exceptions) mode, the [cppreference page for feholdexcept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feholdexcept) has this to say (bold emphasis my own):

> First, saves the current floating-point environment to the object
> pointed to by envp (similar to fegetenv), then clears all
> floating-point status flags, and then installs the non-stop mode:
> future floating-point exceptions will not interrupt execution (will
> not trap), ***until the floating-point environment is restored by
> feupdateenv or fesetenv.***

**However,** this question is tagged [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) and, although the cppreference website is a reliable – and largely accurate – source (for both C++ and C), it **is not the C Standard** and should not be used *in lieu* of that. So, I searched for a similar note in [this C11 Draft Standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), but failed to find one.

The best 'confirmation' I could find is the example given in that draft, in the section on the `feupdateenv` function (§7.6.4.4):

> EXAMPLE Hide spurious underflow floating-point exceptions:
>
> ```c
> #include <fenv.h>
> double f(double x)
> {
>     #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
>     double result;
>     fenv_t save_env;
>     if (feholdexcept(&save_env))
>         return /* indication of an environmental problem */;
>     // compute result
>     if (/* test spurious underflow */)
>         if (feclearexcept(FE_UNDERFLOW))
>             return /* indication of an environmental problem */;
>     if (feupdateenv(&save_env))
>         return /* indication of an environmental problem */;
>     return result;
> }
> ```

I read that example as implicitly indicating that the FP exception mode is fully restored to its saved value by a successful call to `feupdateenv`.

Comment: The description of `feupdateenv` does not say anything about uninstalling the non-stop (continue on floating-point exceptions) mode. It 1) saves the currently raised floating-point exceptions in its automatic storage, 2) installs the floating-point environment represented by the object pointed to by envp, and then 3) raises the saved floating-point exceptions. As I understand, after these actions the non-stop (continue on floating-point exceptions) mode is still installed.

Comment: @pmor So what would the "floating-point environment" entail, if not flags for things like the "non-stop" mode?

Comment: @pmor Also, from [cppreference on feholdexcept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feholdexcept): *future floating-point exceptions will not interrupt execution (will not trap), until the floating-point environment is restored by feupdateenv or fesetenv.*

Comment: @pmor See edit - best I could do, in terms of the actual/draft C Standard.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the EXAMPLE, thanks. However, until it is specified in the C Standard that `feupdateenv` and/or `fesetenv` uninstall the non-stop (continue on floating-point exceptions) mode (if available), it is not clear whether `feupdateenv` and/or `fesetenv` uninstall or not the non-stop (continue on floating-point exceptions) mode. I'd expect them to uninstall it. However, it is not (?) specified in the C Standard. Hence, the confusion.

Comment: @pmor Also, the introduction to §7.6.4 has: *The functions in this section manage the floating-point environment — status flags* ***and control modes*** *— as one entity.*